# Can you make Logic Gates/Computers with Power in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I have been tinkering with the Power System for awhile, and was wondering if anyone knew how to make Logic Gates in Fallout 4, or if it is even possible without making a Mod?

For example, how would you make an AND Gate? You can try and go the Minecraft approach, with 2 Inputs, but what would it toggle on and off, to then give the output? And how would you make it where both Inputs would need to be 1 to get a 1 output?

Comment: Nice question for a beginner, welcome to Arqade!

Comment: Mildly NSFW, but relevant, complex computerised construction in Fallout. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxSw6iDSujg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"And" gates and "or" gates are extremely simple, but I haven't found a way to make a "not" gate (think the inverter in minecraft) necessary to create more complex circuits. Anyway to make an "and" gate, create 2 switches as your input and wire them in series to an output. (like a lamp or pylon tower)

Generator > switch > switch > light

when (and only when) both switches are on, the light will turn on.

Also, "or" gates are the same except wired in parallel rather than series.

Comment: That's not a gate, though, it's a circuit with two switches wired in series. I can't take arbitrary input from another circuit, it requires a user to intervene.

Answer (score 6):

As of the latest Contraptions DLC, there are now fully functional logic gates that are build-able in settlements.

These logic gates do have some confusing properties however. In order for something to properly register on the logic, it must be something that has an on and off state, not just something that allows power to transmit through it. For example, you can't have a switched pylon, connected to a regular pylon, that is then connected to the logic gate. You have to connect the switched pylon to the logic gate directly.